# Permission Error when Compiling C++ code in Cygwin

Tags: c++, cygwin

I'm trying to compile a file in C++ on Cygwin but I keep getting the same error:

```
Hola! ~/projects/basic-cpp $ g++ main.cpp
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: reopening a.exe: Permission denied

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've seen on other questions on Stack Overflow that this can be caused by the executable being currently run, but I know this is not the case. If I run the command with raised permissions it compiles, so it has something to do with not being able to create the file in the directory because it doesn't have permission.

Also, when I get it to compile by using raised permissions, the file isn't writable by the user. If I compile something using java the *.class file isn't user writable either. If I open and save a new file with emacs the file IS user writable. I feel like there's some serious permission issues with my Cygwin install and any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had to fully reinstall Cygwin in order to fix this. Something was seriously wrong. I'm still not sure what caused it.